# RegEx - Is there a way to use a previous match content as variable to use it as a group length?

Tags: c#, regex

I'm searching a way to complete my regex with perfect goal, what I'm trying to do is to use a previous match to use it (the valid value) as a length for the next validation group.

Regex is read step by step so I'm asking if it's possible, I think it's not but if there is a way to do it like this or differently I take it.

I test all my regex on : [regex101](https://regex101.com/)

Thanks for reading,

Strings to evaluate :

Valid

> 15,000000001111111

Not valid

> 15,00000000111111

Actual regex (sadly validate both previous strings):

`/^([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-1][0-9]|12[0-8]),{1}[0-4]{1,128}$/`

I have 3 groups to validate, we have :

The first : `([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-1][0-9]|12[0-8])` Content is between 1 and 128

The second : `,{1}` the comma

The third : `[0-4]{1,128}` Content is between 0 and 4 with a length corresponding to the first group content

What I'm searching for is define X, which is the first group validated, to use it as the third group length, we want to reach something like this :

`([0-9]|[1-9][0-9]|1[0-1][0-9]|12[0-8]),{1}(?(1)[0-4]{*group1 Content*}|*no match*)`

Condition into the third group said :

> if first group is valid then "check third group validation" else "this is a no match"

Comment: So, you want to match 15 digits in the fractional part in `15,000000001111111` because the integer part is `15`, right? This is not possible with plain regex. In C#, it is not. Even if you were to use Perl and its `(?...)` code inserts, it is already a code hack. Now, is it the answer ("No, not possible"), or are you interested in the code solution?

Comment: What is the original condition description?

Comment: You would need to *alternate* all options: [`^(?:1,[0-4]|2,[0-4]{2}|3,`...`|128,[0-4]{128})$`](https://regex101.com/r/TWXsgk/1)

Comment: Actually I was aware of those possibilities, thank you guys, I know that's a bit ugly but I'll go with the @bobblebubble's solution to include it.
That case is just a part of a really bigger regex, I think I just gave birth to a monster ('é_è).